# Storm1.1.0 + kafka0.10.2.1: NoSuchMethodError&ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, opentsdb

I am new to storm and kafka. I want to run a open source project:[github:cestella:streaming_outliers](https://github.com/cestella/streaming_outliers)

This project uses storm0.10.0. However, My storm cluster is storm1.0.3, which is not work for storm0.10.0.

So,I have to change the version of storm and some related packages.

Then, when I run this topology, it will turn out the following errors.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkSend.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:41) at kafka.network.RequestOrResponseSend.(RequestOrResponseSend.scala:44) at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:112) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:98) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:149) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:75) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:65) at org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:103) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:129) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4905$fn__4920$fn__4951.invoke(executor.clj:644) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsGroup$class.newTimer(KafkaMetricsGroup.scala:90) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseMetrics.newTimer(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:26) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseMetrics.(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:35) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStats.(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:47) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:60) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:60) at kafka.utils.Pool$$anonfun$getAndMaybePut$1.apply(Pool.scala:52) at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:70) at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:52) at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.getFetchRequestAndResponseStats(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:64) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.(SimpleConsumer.scala:44) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.(SimpleConsumer.scala:34) at org.apache.storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) at org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:74) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:129) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4905$fn__4920$fn__4951.invoke(executor.clj:644) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66) at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211) at com.yammer.metrics.Metrics.(Metrics.java:21) ... 21 more

And

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.getBoolean(Config.java:354) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.loadStaticVariables(Config.java:620) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.setDefaults(Config.java:532) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.(Config.java:131) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler$TSDBConfig.(TSDBHandler.java:127) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler$TSDBConfig.(TSDBHandler.java:124) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler.configure(TSDBHandler.java:144) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.outlier.OutlierBolt.prepare(OutlierBolt.java:63) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4973$fn__4986.invoke(executor.clj:791) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
>           at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.getBoolean(Config.java:354) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.loadStaticVariables(Config.java:620) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.setDefaults(Config.java:532) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at net.opentsdb.utils.Config.(Config.java:131) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler$TSDBConfig.(TSDBHandler.java:127) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler$TSDBConfig.(TSDBHandler.java:124) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.timeseries.tsdb.TSDBHandler.configure(TSDBHandler.java:144) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at com.caseystella.analytics.outlier.OutlierBolt.prepare(OutlierBolt.java:63) ~[stormjar.jar:1.6.6]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4973$fn__4986.invoke(executor.clj:791) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
>           at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]

Following is the packages' version.

> kafka_version: 0.10.2.1

kafka-clients version: 0.10.2.1

storm_version: 1.1.0

storm-kafka version: 1.1.0

flux_version: 1.1.0

tsdb_version: 2.3.0

There are some methods in the internet say that appending the dependency of kafka-clients can solve the first error. However,it don't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No such method error comes when your application contains multiple versions of the same jar (ex. kafka 0.10.2.1 & 0.10.0.1). Check your project dependencies and remove the older version of the jar.

Comment: I have try this method, but it seems not work.  The error still exists.

Comment: It may be work finally. The first error is due to using old version kafka, in which the method's parameters is not compatible with the new version storm-kafka.

Answer (score 0):

kafka and kafka-clients version in pom.xml should match each other.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```